# discord bot который будет в определенное время писать сообщение в чат

Tags: python, discord-api

Помогите сделать бот для дискорда который будет в определенное время писать сообщение в чат

пытался делать так

```
async def hi():
    await bot.wait_untill_ready()
    channel = client.get_channel("Channel_ID")
    last_message = await bot.send_message(channel, "ponggggg")
    await asyncio.sleep(21600) 

bot.loop.create_task(hi())
```

и так

```
b = datetime.datetime.now()
br = b.hour
t = datetime.time(21,30)
if br == 21:
    print("Hello World!") <- вот это выводит в консоль
    client.send_message(message.channel,"pong!"); <- но как выводить в сам дискорд я хз
```

---

Когда мы делаем ответ на команду в чате я понимаю как выводить сообщение, но когда я задаю вот, то не понимаю
например

```
@commands.command()
async def d(self):  

<-ляляля->

await self.bot.say("текст")
```

Comment: Вот пример бота, который делает, что вам нужно - https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/background_task.py

Answer (score 1):

что бы вывести в сам дискорд попробуйте

```
client.reply("ваш текст");
```

- это отправит сообщение пользователю вроде NICK, ваш текст. Если хотите без упоминания пользователя то

```
message.channel.sendMessage("text");
```