# Отправка сообщения по расписанию с помощью бота дискорд на python

Tags: python, discord.py

Цель заключается в том, чтобы в определенное время в дискорд канал 2 раза в день приходило определенно уведомление (просто текст)

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [discord bot который будет в определенное время писать сообщение в чат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808514/discord-bot-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82)

Comment: Удобный [модуль](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x) для работы с таймерами и временем.

Comment: Попробуйте `schedule`